# Newbie to virtual box can a vm using the same hdd give the host pc viruses

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virtualbox, virus

I just recently got into virtual box and have been using it and I have one question
Let's say my main pc had a 2 ssds and 1 hdd 1 ssd os 1 ssd for fast load time games and the hdd for misc games pics etc
My question is if I use my hdd on my main pc to give the virtual box hdd space if a virus gets installed wouldn't that go to my main hdd?

Comment: From time to time in the virtualization software vulnerabilities are found that allow to break-out from the guest OS to the host OS: In such a case an infection could spread from the guest OS to the host OS (if the virus has the ability to use that vulnerability). In such a case it does not matter which HDDs or SSDs you have mounted in the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines can be sandboxed to prevent virus spread, but for the most part I find sandboxed VMs to be less than useful because their connections to the outside world are very limited.

Otherwise (for network connected machines and drives) any self respecting virus can infect the whole lot. It does not matter what disk in a machine you keep the virtual machine.

Make sure Host and VMs have proper virus protection. Windows 10 Defender is top rated for Windows 10.

I always have 3 VMs running (Windows 7, Kali, Ubuntu) on a Windows 10 host protected by Windows Defender.

A generous dolop of Common Sense goes a long way to avoiding viruses. Make sure your Email machine has top notch spam filtering. Mail.com quarantines all viruses and I never see them.